# Monotouch application is getting crashed in device but works fine in simulator

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm binding a third party(red park sdk) in monotouch. I have created wrapper for red park dll by using monotouch binding project and implement the dll in simple application. On assigning the delegate the application crashes. This my code for assigning the delegate

```
rsc=new RscMgr();
            RscMgrDelegate del=new MyRedParkDelegate();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("this"+del);
            rsc.SetDelegate(del);
```

The crash i'm getting is

```
Incident Identifier: D4781D02-9D0A-427B-BD33-D867720E9CB6
CrashReporter Key:   ecaef65d635cbb77be4760eebfa4b05b6be49112
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         TestRedParkSDK [498]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/5574681C-8028-474D-B0AA-3C71B3C7EA39/TestRedParkSDK.app/TestRedParkSDK
Identifier:      TestRedParkSDK
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-07-12 15:09:48.635 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x2fd00ff8
Crashed Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:

0   CoreFoundation                  0x37391ca0 0x3737b000 + 93344
1   CoreFoundation                  0x373f99c8 0x3737b000 + 518600
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3737c848 0x3737b000 + 6216
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3737c13e 0x3737b000 + 4414
4   CoreFoundation                  0x37391792 0x3737b000 + 92050

362 TestRedParkSDK                  0x00020278 0x1000 + 127608

371 TestRedParkSDK                  0x00263da8 0x1000 + 2502056
372 TestRedParkSDK                  0x00020278 0x1000 + 127608
373 TestRedParkSDK                  0x000fd04c 0x1000 + 1032268
...

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315db3a8 0x315da000 + 5032
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x30560ea4 0x30554000 + 52900
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x30560bc2 0x30554000 + 52162

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315ebcd4 0x315da000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ca3f36 0x33c9b000 + 36662
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ca3cc8 0x33c9b000 + 36040

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315eb470 0x315da000 + 70768
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ca66d0 0x33c9b000 + 46800
2   TestRedParkSDK                  0x001ad9a4 0x1000 + 1755556
3   TestRedParkSDK                  0x001aeaec 0x1000 + 1759980
4   TestRedParkSDK                  0x001ae918 0x1000 + 1759512
5   TestRedParkSDK                  0x001ad71c 0x1000 + 1754908
6   TestRedParkSDK                  0x001b07e8 0x1000 + 1767400
7   Foundation                      0x37c1aa7a 0x37c0a000 + 68218
8   Foundation                      0x37cae58a 0x37c0a000 + 673162
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ca972e 0x33c9b000 + 59182
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ca95e8 0x33c9b000 + 58856

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315ebcd4 0x315da000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ca3f36 0x33c9b000 + 36662
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ca3cc8 0x33c9b000 + 36040

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315db054 0x315da000 + 4180
1   TestRedParkSDK                  0x00250590 0x1000 + 2422160
2   TestRedParkSDK                  0x001f3a72 0x1000 + 2042482
3   TestRedParkSDK                  0x0023ae72 0x1000 + 2334322
4   TestRedParkSDK                  0x0024bf8a 0x1000 + 2404234
5   TestRedParkSDK                  0x0025dd74 0x1000 + 2477428
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ca972e 0x33c9b000 + 59182
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ca95e8 0x33c9b000 + 58856

Thread 6 name:  WebThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315db004 0x315da000 + 4100
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315db1fa 0x315da000 + 4602
2   CoreFoundation                  0x374083ec 0x3737b000 + 578540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37407124 0x3737b000 + 573732
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3738a49e 0x3737b000 + 62622
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3738a366 0x3737b000 + 62310
6   WebCore                         0x32d33c9c 0x32c8a000 + 695452
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ca972e 0x33c9b000 + 59182
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ca95e8 0x33c9b000 + 58856

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00627970    r1: 0x00000004      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0xfefefeff
    r4: 0x00627970    r5: 0x00000002      r6: 0x3fa4bc60      r7: 0x2fd01010
    r8: 0x3fa4cc58    r9: 0x00000002     r10: 0x006555a0     r11: 0x2fd014c0
    ip: 0x00627970    sp: 0x2fd01004      lr: 0x373f99cf      pc: 0x37391ca0
  cpsr: 0x40000030




Kindly help me.Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save `RscMgrDelegate` in a member variable in your class.

If the Garbage Collector is able to collect it (it's not saved in a variable that stays around), then Objective-C will crash when it tries to invoke it.  This could more likely happen on the device, since the Garbage Collector runs more aggressively.